Desplasmolysis while maintaining hypertonicity
I prepared a sample of an onion cell by putting it in a hypertonic solution and was able to observe plasmolysis. However, when I observed it few hours later using a microscope, I found that deplasmolysis had occurred and the cells had returned to normal (not completely but appreciably). How can this be explained?

Welcome to SE Biology. Please do us the courtesy of finishing reading the [Tour] to find out how this site works, and especially the Help section on writing a good question. I have edited your title as an example because the English was unacceptable. However I think it unlikely that anyone can do more than guess at the cause of your problem, if the outcome is contrary to expectation.
